# A system of three `eigenequations' (sort of)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, orthonormal

In my research I have stumbled upon the following problem: Find all pairwise orthonormal triples of vectors $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ ($n \geq 4$) satisfying the three `eigenequations'

$(a\mathbf{A}+b\mathbf{B}-c\mathbf{C})\mathbf{x}=(c-b)bc \,\mathbf{x} \\ (a\mathbf{A}+b\mathbf{B}-c\mathbf{C})\mathbf{y}=(c-a)ca \,\mathbf{y} \\ (a\mathbf{A}+b\mathbf{B}-c\mathbf{C})\mathbf{z}=(a+b)ab \,\mathbf{z}$

where - **and this is crucial** - the $n\times n$ matrices $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B},\mathbf{C}$ themselves depend on $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z}$, respectively, being defined as

$A_{ij} = \delta_{ij}\sum_k D_{kj}|x_k|^2 - x_i D_{ij} \bar{x}_j \\ B_{ij} = \delta_{ij}\sum_k D_{kj}|y_k|^2 - y_i D_{ij} \bar{y}_j \\ C_{ij} = \delta_{ij}\sum_k D_{kj}|z_k|^2 - z_i D_{ij} \bar{z_j}$

where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker symbol and $D_{ij}$ ($i,j =1,\ldots,n$) are certain given coefficients satisfying $D_{ii} = 0$, $D_{ij} = D_{ji} > 0$ for $i \neq j$. Notice that the matrices are positive semi-definite and satisfy $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{B} \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{C} \mathbf{z} = 0$ (I think their rank is actually $n-1$) as well as $\mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{z}^+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{z}, \quad \mathbf{z}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{x}^+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}, \quad \mathbf{x}^+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}$.

Using orthogonality, one can easily show from the equations that all the `mixed terms' vanish, i.e. $\mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z} = 0$ and so on.

As for the scalars $a,b,c$, they are assumed positive and can be shown to be equal to,

$a = \sqrt{\mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{y}} = \sqrt{\mathbf{z}^+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{z}}, \quad b = \sqrt{\mathbf{z}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z}} = \sqrt{\mathbf{x}^+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}}, \quad c = \sqrt{\mathbf{x}^+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}} = \sqrt{\mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}}$.

I've been able to notice that any triple of distinct canonical basis vectors (with arbitrary phase factors) solves the above problem. In other words, taking

$x_j = e^{i\phi_1}\delta_{i_1 j}, \quad y_j = e^{i\phi_2}\delta_{i_2 j}, \quad z_j = e^{i\phi_3}\delta_{i_3 j}$

for any distinct $i_1,i_2,i_3 \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and any angles $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$ does the trick. Sometimes there exist other solutions, e.g. if $D_{ij} = 1 - \delta_{ij}$, then *any* orthonormal triple $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z}$ will do. And so my question is: **Assuming all **$D_{ij}$**'s are distinct (other than **$D_{ii} = 0$** and **$D_{ij} = D_{ji}$**, that is), is it possible to show that the solutions mentioned above are the only ones?**

Let me add that with all of the above in mind, one can rewrite the equations in a quite nice form

$(\frac{\mathbf{B}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}}}-\frac{\mathbf{C}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}}})\mathbf{x}=(\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}}-\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}}) \mathbf{x} \\ (\frac{\mathbf{A}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}}}-\frac{\mathbf{C}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{y}}})\mathbf{y}=(\sqrt{\mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}}-\sqrt{\mathbf{y}^+\mathbf{C}\mathbf{y}}) \mathbf{y} \\ (\frac{\mathbf{A}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{z}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z}}}+\frac{\mathbf{B}}{\sqrt{\mathbf{z}^+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{z}}})\mathbf{z}=(\sqrt{\mathbf{z}^+\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z}}+\sqrt{\mathbf{z}^+\mathbf{B}\mathbf{z}}) \mathbf{z}$

But I've not been able to move much further. I tried playing for a while with determinants, but came back empty-handed. Any hint would be much appreciated, even for the real case.

EDIT: I've noticed that the original system of three `eigenequations' actually concerns one and the same matrix $a\mathbf{A}+b\mathbf{B}-c\mathbf{C}$ and have now included this fact in the question. Also some other minor errors are now corrected.

Comment: To be sure : please confirm that $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker symbol.

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, I confirm. I've now clarifiied that in my question, thanks!